# Programmatically Get Checked In publishing pages from pages library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Am trying to list all publishing checked In pages from pages library. Using following code am getting checked In and Checked out pages. How can I filter out only checked in pages?

```
            SPList pageList = web.Lists["Pages"];
            DataTable dtNews = getNewsTable();
            foreach (SPListItem item in pageList.Items)
            {
                if (item.ContentType.Name == "Article Page")
                {
                    var publishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(item);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am checking file is not checked out and not in drafts

```
foreach (SPListItem item in pageList.Items)
            {
                if (item.ContentType.Name == "Article Page")
                {
                    SPFile file = item.File;
                    if (file.Level != SPFileLevel.Draft && file.Level != SPFileLevel.Checkout)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SPList pageList = web.Lists["Pages"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='int'>0</Value></Eq></Where>";

    foreach (SPListItem item in pageList.GetItems(query))
    {
        if (item.ContentType.Name == "Article Page")
        {
            var publishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not working. The query does not  return any value

Comment: The CAML query will return only checked out files.